# How can I convert Snake case into Start case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

I have an array of strings with values in the Snake case.

I need them to map some inputs.

How can I convert
`'some_string'` into `'Some String'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the input array

   1. [`split('_')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split): Convert string into an array on each `_`
   2. [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array to make [each first char uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)
   3. [`join(' ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join): Convert the array back to a string, joined
      on a space ( )

```js
const inputArray = [ 'some_string', 'foo_bar' ];
const outputArray = inputArray.map((input) => (
  input.split('_').map(s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)).join(' ')
));

console.log(outputArray);
```

Input array:

```json
[ 'some_string', 'foo_bar' ];
```

Will produce:

```json
[
  "Some String",
  "Foo Bar"
]
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but a comment since I happened to be looking at code that did the exact same thing in another answer on SO where the performance was tested, apparently it's faster to do `s[0]` than `charAt(0)`. (Now that I've looked at the stats again, it's barely worth mentioning, difference is negligible.)

Answer (score 1):

You can [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your array doing [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with [Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```js
const arr = ['some_string', 'foo_bar']
const result = arr.map(
  s => s
    .replace(/_/g, ' ')
    .replace(/^\w|\s\w/g, l => l.toUpperCase())
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I've removed the trailing `]` so it won't produce an error. But OP want each word to start with an uppercase, in your answer only the first one is capitalised.

Comment: @0stone0 thank you.. I have fixed

Comment: Note that this answer only works for base ASCII characters. `\w` only matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, meaning that `"nightwish_élan"` would be converted to `"Nightwish élan"`. This might or might not be an issue depending on your scenario.